# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid unknown column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Why does this work fine:

```
Tag.create(game_id: 1, tagged: u)
```

But this:

```
tags = Tag.where(game_id: 1, tagged: u).includes(:tagged)
```

gives error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tags.tagged' in 'where clause': SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags`  WHERE `tags`.`game_id` = 1 AND `tags`.`tagged` = 1
```

BTW, `u` is `ActiveRecord::Base` sublcass.

`Tag` table structure:

```
create_table :tags, force: true do |t|
    t.references :game
    t.references :tagged_by
    t.references :tagged
    t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: is column `tagged` resides in your  `tag` table

Comment: Can you post your `Tag` model?

Comment: also show the table structure

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
tags = Tag.includes(:tagged).where(game_id: 1, tagged_id: u.id)
```